# Glitch effect for widgets on flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

[image]

How could I get a glitch effect, like in the image above in flutter? I want my widgets to randomly glitch out.

https://giphy.com/explore/glitch

Something like that, but a lot more intense like in the pictures. How could I apply an effect like that to widgets on flutter? So that they randomly glitch out, and give that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experimenting with glitch effects few weeks ago. Maybe it will give you some ideas how to implement what you what. https://github.com/kherel/flutter_fun

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/glitcheffect

It is very easy to implement. Simply wrap your widget in the GlitchEffect Widget.

```
GlithEffect(
  child: Text(
   'Flutter',
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.red),
  ),
);
```